# Rasterizing Shapefile, using other shapefile as Mask

Tags: qgis, python, masking, rasterization

I have a shapefile (ShapeY) of European extend and want to rasterize each time only a certain area of the shape (ShapeX) (i have the shapes indicating the prevailing extend) with python and QGis.

However so far i have not found a way to write the code in a manner that it already uses Shape X as mask.

My code reads as following:

```
err = gdal.RasterizeLayer(target_raster, (3,2,1), source_layer1, options=["ATTRIBUTE=%s" % RASTERIZE_COLOR_FIELD1])
```

The only solution i found was clipping the resulting layer afterwards with Shape X, but this takes significantly much time. I assume there is a smarter way of initially setting the mask while rasterizing?

Comment: With gdal_rasterize http://www.gdal.org/gdal_rasterize.html you could use -te option for defining target extents. Since GDAL 2.1 you can use gdal_rasterize. I don't know how to do the same with Python from QGIS but I believe that it is possible. Perhaps you can take the envelope of the shape X and use that as an extent when the GeoTIFF is created.

Comment: But as i understand it there the target extend is a rectangle defined by x/y min/max. I dont see how it is possible to set the outline of a certain layer as extend.